# How do you say "yes you can" in the given situation?

Tags: expressions

I work at an online shopping website.

One of the buyers, whose account used to be restricted and was reinstated again, left an inquiry about whether he can make purchases with his account again or not.

Since his account is not blocked or restricted anymore, he can use his account like any other buyers.

So, what should I say to the buyer to inform that he can use his account now, and make purchases again?

Actually, I need to write email to the buyer. But I’ve never written business email before and I am not a native English speaker, so I don’t know what the proper response is for that situation.

Comment: Thank you :) I didn’t know the difference between english and ell website!

Comment: Hello, ninanina. Both ELL and ELU (shall we say more advanced) examine individual word and grammatical usages. You might try at Writers.SE, though I don't know whether they give advice on business communications.

Comment: Can you just delete your question with the delete button under your post? You're not supposed to edit it to remove everything.

Answer (score 1):

One term for the situation is *Your account has been reinstated*. Or *recovered*.

A business email should be as polite or business like as a letter. Nothing personal or overly friendly but very polite.  Since you are working for the paying customer your job is to solve their problems and tell them when you have done so. When you are not working you can depend on others business owners to solve your problems.

You address them with Dear Sir or Madam if you don't have their name. Use *Mr. Name* or *Ms. Name* if you do have it. Tell them how pleased you are they contacted you and assure them that the earlier problem has been solved. You may thank them for their patience and look forward to serving them in the future.

It is not unusual to find files of letters with the suitable language for several different situations but I think this would do the job.